# In node,Upload large zip csv and get back first 10 rows in response

Tags: node.js

In node, I want to upload a large zip CSV file( up to 50 MB which can be decompressed to 2 GB), in the same uploading request I want the first 10 lines to return in the response.
Is it possible to decompress a small stream from the zip and return the response, I have tried multiple node packages but not able to do so if possible, Please can you show me a working example

Comment: From what you've tried, what was the reason it didn't work? did it return more or less than expected?

Comment: It was decompressing all the file at once.

Comment: You cannot open a file from an archive without extracting it first. That's LAW.

Comment: @darklightcode not necessarily true, Node.js `zlib` supports unzipping from a stream, which doesn't need to read the whole file.

Comment: @Neverever Yes, but that CSV file that must be accessed to retrieve the lines, cannot be read without extracting it to some folder(temp)